# React Native: Error calling JSTimers.CallTimers

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, expo

I am trying to run my app on Android (One plus 6t). This was working fine before making a call to firebase but as soon as I add the line `onSend={Fire.shared.send}` to Chat.js, the app crashes. The logs just show **Uncaught Error: Error calling JSTimers.CallTimers**. Haven't seen this error anywhere else. Does anyone know what's the issue?

Here's the snack: https://snack.expo.io/@adititipnis/community

Comment: i have the same issue, i just created another project, and the problem persist, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can get this error if you omit an await call when sending JS objects to the native side, so the promise gets passed rather than the result.

I'm using the typical async sleep pattern that wraps setTimeout, so that may also be a factor in the way this error presents itself, I'm not entirely sure.

This is untested, but something like this should reproduce it:

```
// some async func
const asyncGetResult = async () => {
    await sleep(17);
    // etc.
    return Promise.resolve(result);
};    

// this should cause the error:
MyNativeComponent.nativeMethod({
    result: asyncFunc() // <- missing 'await'
});

// this should not cause the error:
MyNativeComponent.nativeMethod({
    result: await asyncFunc()
});
```

This can be difficult to track down if you don't know what you're looking for. I resorted to process of elimination, reverting changes file by file until I found the offending line. Hopefully this saves someone some time.